# Going from, SELECT * FROM users WHERE url = "pretty url", to displaying 1 row from database with Lithium Framework

Tags: php, mysql, sql, url, lithium

Hi I am new to php and mysql and jumped right into using the Lithium framework.....I know, bad idea.

BUT basically my question is, how do I go from;

```
$users = \app\models\Users::findByUrl($this->request->query['url']);
return array(
  'users' => $users,
 );
```

in my UsersController to actually echo'ing 1 specific row of data in my users/index.php.html page, according to the query string in my url?

My desired structure is localhost/users/"url", and "url" is a value in my mysql db labeled "url" in my Users table. e.g. localhost/users/Bob. "Bob" is "url" value.

My users/index.php.html page is using foreach ($users as $user) to echo the information like this;

> `<?=$user->firstname ?>`

**Snag and Confusion:**

When I was using;

```
$users = \app\models\Users::find('all');
return array(
 'users' => $users,
);
```

in my UsersController, the users/index.php.html page retrieved all the users in my database.

The content displays correctly, BUT I need the data from just the clicked-on user, so this is when I started using; `$users = \app\models\Users::findByUrl($this->request->query['url']);`

When linking to the users page this is how I do it;

```
<?php if( $user->avatar ):?> 
 <a href="/users/<?=$user->url?>">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="/img/users/<?=$user->avatar?>" />  
 </a> 
<?php else: ?>
```

Not sure if I need to add conditions to my controller, add something to my router, change my htaccess, or do something with params.... Pleease help, any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finders return everything by default. If you want a single object, do:

`Users::findFirstByUrl($this->request->query['url'])`

...which is short-hand for:

`Users::first(['conditions' => ['url' => $this->request->query['url']]])` or
`Users::find('first', ['conditions' => ['url' => $this->request->query['url']]])`.